# Certificate issues with svcutil and SoapUI (browsing wsdl using Chrome works)

Tags: wcf, https, windows-server-2012, client-certificates, svcutil.exe

I was not in this company when 99% of certificates were installed on this one server, and now we got bunch of them.
The problem is we're a client of a WCF WS from another company, to which we can only connect through a browser, which displays the WSDL just fine.

Both svcutil and SoapUI complain about connection issues. The guys from the other side confirmed that they removed the client ssl certificate requirement for mutual auth, and now we can't find what other issue could there be that only hinders connectivity using applications like svcutil or soapui, but not chrome.

Answer (score 0):

It was the wrong user under whom the service was running, so when we disabled proxy for that user, the service started talking.
The solution was to return the service under Local System account.